# Google Play Services and version 2 of the Google Maps Android API, Authorization failure

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to build an Android application using the Google Play Services (revision 5) and version 2 of the Google Maps Android API.

I read carefully the documents at :

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api

In order to be sure, I just copied the sample app from :
~/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/samples

In this code, I just changed the developper key and the targetSdkVersion (16 -> 17) inside the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapdemo"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.1.0" >

<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<!-- End of copy. -->
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/demo_title" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXmyXkeyXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BasicMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/basic_map" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/camera_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CircleDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/circle_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EventsDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/events_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".GroundOverlayDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/groundoverlay_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LayersDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/layers_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LocationSourceDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/locationsource_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MarkerDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/marker_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OptionsDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/options_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PolygonDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/polygon_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PolylineDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/polyline_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProgrammaticDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/programmatic_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TileOverlayDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/tile_overlay_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UiSettingsDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/uisettings_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RawMapViewDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/raw_mapview_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RetainMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/retain_map" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MultiMapDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/multi_map_demo" />
</application>
```

The Google Play Library Project is correctly set in the project properties.

I didn't modify the proguard.cfg standard file.

Launching "Google Maps API Demos" on my Motorola Xoom with android 4.1.2, and clicking on "Basic Map", returns a blank screen without any map.

My logcat contains :

```
03-17 14:07:13.450: E/Google Maps Android API(17988): Authorization failure.
```

In my API Console, "Google Maps Android API v2" is on.

I created a key for Android apps, and my console displays :

```
Key for Android apps (with certificates)
API key:    XXXXXXXXXXXmyXkeyXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Android apps:   XXXXXXXXXXXmyXSHA1XXXXXXXXXXXXX;com.example.mapdemo
Activated on:   Mar 17, 2013 4:28 AM
Activated by:    you
```

Do you understand what is wrong ?

Comment: Did you check the services that you allowed? Go to services and see if Google maps API v2 and few others are checked. If now then check them.

Comment: In the Google Play Services API console, when you added the hash of your key, did you use the correct package name? (The package name there must match the package name of the app you're trying to run.)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer : if I export my app in a signed apk, push it to the tablet and install it, I'm able to see the map correctly. Thanks for your answers.

To debug the app, you need to generate a key with the debug certificate fingerprint, as explained in :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#displaying_certificate_information

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue, posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220262/google-map-sdk-map-set-up-authorization-failure-ensure-that-the-following-cor).  To be able to launch from the IDE, add the debug/development SHA1 fingerprint to the API console along with the production one you made from your own keystore.

Just run from command line `keytool -list -v -keystore <keystoreName>.keystore` for both `debug.keystore` (in `~/.android` directory) and also `<yourKeystore>.keystore` (to use when you sign .apks)

This will give you two SHA1 fingerprints, add them both to the `Google Maps Android API v2` in the Google Cloud Console, now you have one for dev and one for live.