# google-map sdk map set up - Authorization failure, Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console

Tags: android, macos, google-maps, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

In the process of porting a recent iOS project onto Android (running OS X), which uses Google Maps API.  I have been through this process for Android before no problems, and not a hiccup during setup for iOS either.  So I am not sure what is going on here

```
11-26 14:21:48.714: E/Google Maps Android API(20362): Authorization failure.  
Please see     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.

11-26 14:21:48.719: E/Google Maps Android API(20362): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: 
Package Name: com.***.*****, 
API Key: ************************************, 
Certificate Fingerprint: *********************************************
```

Here's what I have done/checked:

- restarted ADT/Eclipse/Mac
- turned device off/on, cleared memory, uninstalled/re-installed the app
- ADB lost the ability to see the device for a while but now it's changed it's mind and it happy again
- Generated a new keystore to sign the app with
- used keytool -list -v -keystore  to output the fingerprint
- Put said fingerprint in the Google Maps Android API v2 (which is ON/enabled) in API console

And no matter how many things I refresh or re-do to make sure they're done properly, the app still complains about the fingerprint not matching?  It's the fingerprint in the log that seems to be wrong.

When the app is exported and signed into .apk file what I believe to be the correct SHA1 fingerprint is  presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found quite a simple solution to this issue!

Although the signed .apk I was making with my new keystore had the certificate which was correctly registered in the API console.  When I was launching the app from Eclipse it was using `debug.keystore` located in `~/.android/` to sign the app.  For that fingerprint to work I would have needed to install the app from the .apk instead of launching from Eclipse

So if we repeat the process of getting the SHA1 certificate fingerprint for the debug keystore as well like this: `keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore`, then add that fingerprint in the API console we essentially have dev/live fingerprints registered next to each other, and it won't matter whether we launch from Eclipse or install from .apk (or Google Play etc)